# How do I sample a dataset based on a column value?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, sampling

I have a dataset with 150,000 data points. Each of the data points has a few fields, including a value column. I'd like to sample the dataset so that the rows with a higher value more likely to be selected than the items with a lower value. So based on the example below, in the new dataset, there'll be a lot more items with value 1000 than items with value 5.

I'm not sure about the Pandas way to do this. Please can anyone help?

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id    description    number    value ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 0   A           1           20       ║
║ 1   A           11          50       ║
║ 2   A           1           10       ║
║ 3   A           14          1000     ║
║ 4   A           1           20       ║
║ 5   A           13          50       ║
║ 6   A           1           800      ║
║ 7   A           1           30       ║
║ 8   A           13          5        ║
║ 9   A           12          500      ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Many thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sample from both, you can use a groupby function to sample different numbers of elements for each value. The weights argument can be used to get different weights for the different values.
[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html?highlight=dataframegroupby%20sample#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample)

```py
df_values = df.groupby("value").sample(n=100, weights=[1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas `sample` method and provide a `weights` argument which in this case would be your `df["value"]`. See [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html).

```
df.sample(n=10, weights=df["value"])
```

Comment: Thanks for this example - I was not aware of it! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use sample method with weights as the value of column

```
df.sample(n,weights="value")
```

Comment: Thanks for this example - I was not aware of it!